# Shorthand for `git checkout <tree-ish> -B CURRENT_BRANCH`?

Tags: git

Is there a git command that's equivalent to below, but doesn't require me typing the `CURRENT_BRANCH` part each time?

```
git checkout <tree-ish> -B CURRENT_BRANCH
```

For example, I'm on branch *master* and want to move it back to *origin/master*, so I type `git checkout -B master origin/master`.  Or, maybe I want to move it back to *HEAD~* so I type `git checkout -B master HEAD~`.  --Notice, the `-B master` part seems superfluous because I'm already on *master*.

(I don't want to `reset --hard` because that'll destroy dirty files.)

I'm looking for an alternative mainly because I tend to accidentally type *`git checkout -B <tree-ish>`* with ensuring confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases seems to be the only way to go at this point:

```
git config --global alias.become '!git checkout -B "$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)"'
```

e.g.:

```
$ git checkout foo
$ git become HEAD~
Reset branch 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rev-parse` to get the current branch name :

```
git checkout -B $( git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD ) origin/$( git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD )
```

You could create an alias **current-branch** that returns the current branch, and another alias **current-checkout** that checkouts the current branch (change the command aliases as wanted) :

```
# Add the current branch alias
git config --global alias.current-branch 'rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'

# Add the checkout current branch alias
git config --global alias.checkout-current '!git checkout -B $( git current-branch ) origin/$( git current-branch )'

# Try the command
git checkout-current
```

**EDIT**

You could also use `git reset --mixed` or `git reset --soft` with a ref, depending on what you want to do (those will keep your "dirty" files).

Comment: Good idea with using aliases.  I don't need the `origin/master` part hard-coded because that part should be variable.  (I've edited the question to clarify this.)  I think a problem with the alias is that I'll end up creating a branch named `HEAD` if I'm not on a branch.